Github pull, clone etc works but unable to perform Push
I have write access to the Repo. I am able to perform clone, pull etc but only git push is not working. Also I am able to push changes from Github web portal. Its not giving any error details just giving fatal info. Please help
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Checked the SSH keys & other auth related possible issues. Its not related.


Please check if there is a remote URL set.
git remove -v

If you set remote URL, then please try with this
git push [remote-url name] -f


Tried this. No luck :(

it may be you didn't set remote url or didn't set config for profile.

Remote url is set. All config looks good. However pull, clone are working fine.

Ensure that your Git configuration is correct, especially the user.name and user.email settings. You can check and set these configurations using:
git config --list

Look for name and email, if not same as yours then update it by following commands:
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
git config --global user.email "your_email@example.com"


Thanks @Nie
I think the git config is fine. As pull is working fine
